# IBM Cloud Code Engine: App fails to start after enforcing private endpoint for Container Registry

Tags: security, ibm-cloud, serverless, container-registry, ibm-cloud-code-engine

I have an app deployed to IBM Cloud Code Engine (CE). The app image is stored in the Container Registry. So far I have used public endpoints, e.g., **us.icr.io**. To tighten security, I [enabled private endpoint access to the registry](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Registry?topic=Registry-registry_private).

A while later, I noticed that my CE app failed when starting up after scaling to zero. Is this related to the security changes? How can I address it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Code Engine project and for the app I had configured

- [registry credentials](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-add-registry) including the registry address
- the image specification.

Both contained references to the public endpoint. After updating both settings to the private endpoint, e.g., **private.us.icr.io** the app redeployed and then started again.